# Encoding Log Message to improve storage space on embedded system

Tags: logging, encoding, embedded

I have logging Service running in my embedded system, it log's messages received from Application, string literals are log directly as a result space usage is more.

I am looking for suitable technique to encode string literals to some code during compile time, and regenerate the string using suitable decoder.

Note:
1) Many services log message, i need to take care of feasibility of implementing the solution.
2) If there exist better approach, i would appreciate if you share the links.

Comment: Do you log arbitrary messages logged? Or can you come up with a set of messages that you need? In the second case you could implement a specific logging for each message that only stores the actual interesting data.

Comment: @SandroMeier Logs are arbitrary in nature. Any technique to log arbitrary in efficient way

Answer (score 0):

One quite effective approach to handling log string literals in a C/C++ environment is to allocate them to a distinct linker section, which is stripped from the final binary.

The log statements are defined in such a way as to compile to pointers to these strings, and it's the pointer values themselves (or offsets from a base address if this saves space) that are stored in the log.

The stripped strings section can then be used to reconstruct the full log string from the values in the abbreviated log.

Naturally, the specific means of achieving this varies between platforms, toolchains, etc, and is complicated by the inclusion of non-literal data in the log entries - but all quite feasible in an embedded context.